# Displaying Throughput in flexible file writer in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to Jmeter,i need to print the throughput in Flexible file writer,How can we achieve in jmeter? Since we can display Latency ,Response time and other required details expect throughput.Which will be helpful in creating consolidated report,For throughput we have to check other report separately.

Comment: By default, Flexible File Writer will not support Throughput. You can leverage `Aggregate Report` to write `Throughput` data. Run your tests in NON-GUI mode and then load the jtl file into `Aggregate Report`.

Answer (score 0):

I've never written reports to the Flexible File Writer before but I found this link [here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) that documents the plugin.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but you can add the "Assertion Results" listener to your plan or threadgroup and specify the output file type and path. [AssertionResultsScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn2aj.png)